# При отступе блок сунет за собой родительский блок HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: e.g.]

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
#header {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 background: #ddd;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
.mw {
 max-width: 1170px;
 height: 100vh;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#header_nav {
 width: 1190px;
 margin-top: 35px;
 background: #fff;
 height: 90px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Umbrella</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <div class="mw">
   <div id="header_nav">
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как сделать так, что бы белый блок сунулся внутри желтого? Есть идея с использование `float: left`, но она мне кажется неверной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день.

Попробуйте:

```
.mw {
    max-width: 1170px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
```

Подробнее https://htmlacademy.ru/courses/44/run/10